# Spring mvc - error with white space in file name for download

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm facing an issue with Spring mvc to download files that contains a white space in the name.
What I'm trying to do is to use the resource resolver built-in Spring MVC to download files from a remote host.

I'm using Spring security along with Spring MVC but for test without applying any security on the specific pattern

> Spring Security configuration:

```
    <http>
....
    <intercept-url pattern="/test download/**" access="permitAll" requires-channel="https"  />
...
</http>
```

Then the request arrive on the MVC dispatcher where is configured a resource resolver as such:

> Spring MVC configuration:

```
<mvc:resources  mapping="/test download/**" location="http://localhost:10089/test/" />
```

The configuration works just fine for files that does not have space in the name. Enabling debug log on Spring modules I see that both requests (with or without space in the file name) are handled in the same exact way. 
Below log of the Spring dispatcher servlet while resolving both calls.

> 1st test path : /test download/file.txt

```
... after security filters ..
DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher' processing GET request for [/portal/test%20download/file.txt]
DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /test download/file.txt
DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/test download/file.txt]
DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /test download/file.txt
DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/test download/file.txt]
DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Matching patterns for request [/test download/file.txt] are [/test download/**]
DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - URI Template variables for request [/test download/file.txt] are {}
DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapping [/test download/file.txt] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[URL [http://localhost:10089/test/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@2a6eb843]]] and 1 interceptor
DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/portal/test%20download/file.txt] is: -1
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

> Result: `Content of the file is shown in the browser as expected`
>
> 2nd test path: /test download/test file.txt

```
... after security filters ..
DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher' processing GET request for [/portal/test%20download/test%20file.txt]
DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /test download/test file.txt
DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/test download/test file.txt]
DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /test download/test file.txt
DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/test download/test file.txt]
DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Matching patterns for request [/test download/test file.txt] are [/test download/**]
DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - URI Template variables for request [/test download/test file.txt] are {}
DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapping [/test download/test file.txt] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[URL [http://localhost:10089/test/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@2a6eb843]]] and 1 interceptor
DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/portal/test%20download/test%20file.txt] is: -1
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

> Result: `Http 404 is returned`

The 2 files are in the same folder of the host, I tested both using a local server for the files and a remote server with the same result.

I was trying to resolve my needs just using the Spring configuration since what I need is basically similar to a proxy, but with the Security rules applied.

> Spring MVC version: 4.1.6.RELEASE
>
> Spring Security version:3.2.5.RELEASE

Any idea why this is happening ?

**UPDATE**

After Frederik hint i configured the tomcat that I'm using for test as remote host to manage utf-8  and i discovered that when it handles the request coming from Spring it returns 505.

Simple call from browser to remote host:

> "GET /test/test%20file.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 15

Call received through Spring:

> "HEAD /test/test file.txt HTTP/1.1" 505 -

I did try creating the file with %20 in the name before even configuring the connector and it did not work, so probably even before the encoding was working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has been solved by creating a custom resource handler.

What we did in details was creating a class loaded at start-up as configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


    /**
     *
     * Add ResourceResolver that fix the whitespace problem in filename url.
     * resources that needs this fix must be configured here instead of inside xml
     *
     * @param registry
     */
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addResourceHandler("/test download/**")
                .addResourceLocations("http://localhost:10089/test/")
                .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new CustomPathResourceResolver())
                ;
    }


}
```

And CustomPathResourceResolver is

```
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceResolver;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CustomPathResourceResolver extends PathResourceResolver implements ResourceResolver {

    @Override
    protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath, Resource location) throws IOException {
        //fixes problems with whitespaces in url
        resourcePath = resourcePath.replace(" ","%20");
        return super.getResource(resourcePath, location);
    }
}
```

The replace is not the most elegant solution :) probably but for our simple needs is enough for now.

Answer (score 0):

The handler responsible for looking up the resources based on the URL, uses the `HandlerMapping .PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE`, which corresponds to the `/**` value you have configured in the mapping.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java#L407

I'm quite sure that the path used to get the file contains the escape-characters. So it will look for a file called `test%20file.txt`. You can verify if this is the case, by adding a file in your `test download` folder with that name.

Spring actually decodes the URL - can you check if your tomcat/container actualy ahs the UTF-8 charset filter on?

Comment: How are you displaying the URL in the browser? Maybe you can try encoding the URL, prior to displaying it in the browser: `java.net.URLEncoder.encode(url,"UTF-8")`

Comment: The issue here seems that after the URL is decoded from the Spring Security layer is not re-encoded by the Resource Handler. Debugging the default resource handler (used in the class you posted) the white spaces is not re-encoded. In debug I overwritten the value at runtime  (thanks eclipse for that) with %20 and the file was found without problem. So I think the only solution for now is to extend the default Resource handler adding to the resolver a "re-encode" step for the specific path "/test download/**.